# Why do we need to bind a event handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bind

I understand you might feel this is a redundant question but hear me out.

I am working with React class components and I just learnt that we need to bind a event handler function in the constructor of the component in order to access `this.setState()` inside the event handler. Now from what I understand about JavaScript classes, `this` can be accessed by any method inside a class.

To demonstrate what I am saying, here is the code:

```js
class Parent {
  setState() {
    console.log("Set State is called");
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  eventHandler() {
    this.setState();
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Render method called");
    console.log("assume an event happened and event handler is called");
    this.eventHandler();
  }
}

new Child().render()
```

The output of the above code is:

```
Render method called
assume an event happened and event handler is called
Set State is called
```

Contrasting the above code with how react works (i.e. assuming `setState` is a method defined in the class `React.Component`), why does react throw an error when `this.setState()` is called inside an event handler?

Comment: This may help you: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key point I missed out on was that a method that is defined inside a class loses its context when it is reassigned.

So when we do,

```
<SomeComponent onClick={eventHandler} />
```

the `eventHandler` is reassigned to some other variable and is called internally by react. Because of this reassignment, the `eventHandler` will lose its context and when called by react internally, it wont have `this`.

To explicitly bind `this` to the `eventHandler` so that it doesn't lose its context even after reassigning, we do:

```
this.eventHandler = this.eventHandler.bind(this)
```

Please refer [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/) article for an in-depth explanation.