# JavaScript - How to use the methods of a class in other methods of that class

Tags: javascript

I don't understand if it is possible to use class methods in another method of the same class. If so, where am I making a mistake

```
class Form {

    constructor (classForm, name, email, phone, text) {
        this.form = document.querySelector(`.contactForm`);
        this.name = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${name}]`);
        this.email = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${email}]`);
        this.phone = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${phone}]`);
        this.text = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${text}]`);
        this.submit = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=submit]`);
    }

    checkPhone () {
        return this.phone.value.length >= 12;
    }

    formSubmit (el) {
        console.log(this.checkPhone())
        el.preventDefault();
        console.log('not')
    }

}

const formContact = new Form("contactForm", "nameUser", "emailUser", "phoneUser");
formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit);
```

**"Uncaught TypeError: this.checkPhone is not a function"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that inside your `formSubmit` function the `this` value isn't what you think.
A way to fix that would be to bind it to your classe's `this`.

You could either do that when you call the function, of you can just add it to your constructor.

Something like this:

```js
class Form {

  constructor(classForm, name, email, phone, text) {
    this.form = document.querySelector(`.contactForm`);
    this.name = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${name}]`);
    this.email = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${email}]`);
    this.phone = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${phone}]`);
    this.text = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=${text}]`);
    this.submit = document.querySelector(`.contactForm [name=submit]`);

    this.formSubmit = this.formSubmit.bind(this);
    //this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.formSubmit);
  }

  checkPhone() {
    return this.phone.value.length >= 12;
  }

  formSubmit(el) {
    console.log(this.checkPhone())
    el.preventDefault();
    console.log('not')
  }

}

const formContact = new Form("contactForm", "nameUser", "emailUser", "phoneUser", "textUser");
formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit);
```

```html
<form action="#" class="contactForm">
  <input type="text" name="nameUser" />
  <input type="email" name="emailUser" />
  <input type="text" name="phoneUser" />
  <input type="text" name="textUser" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**idea 1**

You can also see at the end of the constructor i have added a extra `this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.formSubmit);` (which is commented out).

If you really want a class to take care of the form, then why not let the class listen to the form submit. This means you would not need to call it from outside the class.

(you could replace your `formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit);` with the `this.form.addEventListener('submit', this.formSubmit);` inside the class constructor)

**Idea 2**

Something else you could try would be to change your `formSubmit` into an arrow function:

```
formSubmit = (el} => {
    ...
}
```

Arrow functions don't have the same `this` as normal function

**Info**

Here is some [useful information about the `bind` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

**PS:**

Also, you forgot the "textName" parameter on your `new Form(...)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I did not forget "textName", I made a test class to understand how classes work in JavaScript :)

Comment: @SerhiiPrudkyi glad i could help. If you want to learn about it, i think MDN always has nice information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 2):

Basically, because in JavaScript, `this` reference inside functions can be bound to different objects depending on where the function is being called.

You can fix this with two techniques:

1. Use [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind `this` when you pass a method as a callback.

```js
class Form {
    // ...

    checkPhone () {
        return this.phone.value.length >= 12;
    }

    formSubmit (el) {
        console.log(this.checkPhone())
        el.preventDefault();
        console.log('not')
    }
}

const formContact = new Form("contactForm", "nameUser", "emailUser", "phoneUser");
formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit.bind(formContact));
```

2. Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which have different semantics than traditional JavaScript functions.

```js
class Form {
    // ...

    checkPhone = () => {
        return this.phone.value.length >= 12;
    };

    formSubmit = (el) => {
        console.log(this.checkPhone())
        el.preventDefault();
        console.log('not')
    };
}

const formContact = new Form("contactForm", "nameUser", "emailUser", "phoneUser");
formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit);
```

I believe this question is quite common, but if you would like to understand the issue in more depth I have left some links below:

---

#### FreeCodeCamp

- [The Complete Guide to this in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-complete-guide-to-this-in-javascript/)
- [This is why we need to bind event handlers in Class Components in React](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/)

---

#### StackOverflow

- [JavaScript: bind an object's method to event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586072/javascript-bind-an-objects-method-to-event-handler)
- [What is the use of the JavaScript 'bind' method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/what-is-the-use-of-the-javascript-bind-method)
- [Why do we need to bind a event handler in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61388040/why-do-we-need-to-bind-a-event-handler-in-react)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You need to `bind` the `formContact.formSubmit` function in the event listener to the `formContact`: the scope of `this` inside of the event listener will be `window` if you don't bind it.

```
formContact.form.addEventListener("submit", formContact.formSubmit.bind(formContact));
```